xrayui 3X-UI - How do I assign a specific IP address to a subscription or client?
My virtual server has several IP addresses. How do I assign a specific IP address to a subscription or client?
I don't know how to do this, if anyone knows, please tell me.
I assume this needs to be done in routing, but I can't figure out how to do it.
